# IntelliJ IDEA changes Java Compiler automatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I don't know what's the reason, but at some point IntelliJ changes my compiler version from `Groovy-Eclipse` to `Javac`.

Then the compilation fails. Project defaults are already set to Groovy-Eclipse.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Is it a Maven project? There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202286

Comment: Yes, it is a maven-project (multi-module). Thanks a lot, the workaround with setting `maven.import.compiler.arguments` to false in Registry (use Help | Find Action and type 'registry') helped.
The actual problem seems to be, that in **different modules** are **different compiler** are set for maven-compiler-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Preferences` and uncheck `Detect compiler automatically`. The location of this setting you can see in the picture below:

[image]